# How to create a PyroCMS view or layout for PyroStream Data witout using a page?

Tags: pyrocms

I have created two Streams in PyroCMS. **I would like to display this data** via a URL (obviously) **without having it associated to a Page in the CMS** (which the Client is able to edit).

Is there any way to do this via the system/cms/config/routes.php or does this need to be a stand-alone module or widget to achieve this?

I am new to PyroCMS so could be way off here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to output data from a URL then it needs to be a page, or a module controller.

A module controller would be tricky, so make it into a page and just don't let your client edit pages using permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Well perhaps a module is just the thing you need.. If I understand you correctly you want to just have an empty page without layout and some results generated via a module, widget, plugin etc.. I recommend to just create a module and set layout to falls in its method.:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
  exit('No direct script access allowed');

class StreamDisplay extends Public_Controller {

  public function index() {
    $this->template->set_layout(FALSE);

    echo 'Some awesome streamdata from Pyro streams';
    //Or load a view just to be clean:
    $this->template->title('Stream')->build('index');
  }

}
```